# How to add filter for file name special characters validation in Plupload API?

Tags: api, plupload

```
plupload.addI18n({
'Filename' : '<%=sw.getValue("_Filename_Uploader")%>',
});
filters : [
{title : "<%=sw.getValue("_BrowsePurpose")%>", extensions : "jpg,gif,png,jpeg"},
```

Same way i need to add filter for filename validation in PL UPLOAD API, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a [custom filter](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/File-Filters) to your Plupload config.